# How does one reload nginx with the latest scripts?

Tags: python, django, nginx

in a production environment running nginx/django that I didn't originally create I had to modify a python file in the django solution.

What would be the typical way to get nginx to run the new changes to the python file?

I assume that it won't run it without some kind of reload due to the .pyc files (although I didn't see a .pyc for the specific file I edited, otherwise I would have just deleted it to see if it would cause the system to pick up my changes.)

nginx.conf

```
user vagrant;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;



    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**Here is the sites-available config part that mentions wsgi:**

```
    location @hems {
            include uwsgi_params;
            #uwsgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
            client_max_body_size       10m;
            uwsgi_pass         django-back;
```

**I noticed there is a wsgi.py that exports application, and here is a setting from settings.py referenceing wsgi:**

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'symhome.wsgi.application'

Comment: Ah. Then you have uWSGI and not WSGI. Then my answer won't help. I've just deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually trying `touch <yourproject>/wsgi.py` should reload the project (the directory where **settings.py** exists), or if that does not work try `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`.